# How can I pop up a element from a website into a windows with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to pop up an image or a div/class from a website into a window with Greasemonkey, how can I do it?

For example, I want to pop up the stackoverflow logo to a small window (the size of the logo) when I enter the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.open), which will open a new window whose size you can dictate.

Comment: Actually, it's not a window that I want to open. How can I explain... I want to open a little window only with the content wanted, but not a new window of the browser, just a little popup window

Comment: ah I see, [these are some solutions using jQuery](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts), and you can [include jquery in a userscript with @require](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries).